# Spam in [astro] tag

Tags: discussion, spam

Some spammer (Vedic Folks) have started spamming on SO. I've found them rejecting suggested edits on [astro](/questions/tagged/astro) tag. However, some robo-reviewers have accepted their [suggested spam edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3859274) for the tag body, leaving the tag summary empty.

1. How to clean the tag body? I can't delete tag body because system requires tag summary to be not-empty
2. The review system have obviously failed, if the reviewers have accepted such edit. Is it possible for moderators to ping the reviewers somehow to notify them?

Comment: Never mind, found the tag excerpt; I'll clean this up.

Comment: I've given the tag an excerpt based on a quick google. Lets see if we can ping a moderator to give those robo-reviewers some stern talking to; all 3 deserve some time off reviewing for this in my opinion.

Comment: One with 10k rep, one with 14.5k and one with 7.7k. ಠ_ಠ.

Comment: So far, the spammer created one spam answer and the tag wiki edits; one approved, one rejected. I flagged the spam answer.

Comment: Spam account has been nuked.

Comment: *"Paging minitech. Cleanup on isle 5"*

Comment: True problem is the reviewers who must be at least warned, if not banned from reviewing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I contacted all three in comments on their most recent answers. Two apologized and promised betterment.

Comment: Well done @Martijn! :)

Comment: What happened to the other user then?